# Magento 2 how to make sticky header for frontend?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, header

I am using Magento 2.1.5 and I need to make header sticky for the frontend. how can I make header sticky?

When user scroll page then header should be sticky at the top, how we can do this? this code should apply for desktop view only not for a mobile and iPad view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried but not working in magento 2

Comment: Linked answer is for Magento 1.9, but this question is for Magento 2.1., so it shouldn't be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 6):

You can add this piece of javascript code to your custom.js file and you can call this custom.js file either in `default_head_blocks.xml` or `requirejs-config.js`

```
require([ "jquery" ], function($){

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top && !($('#header').hasClass('sticky'))){
    $('#header-2').addClass('sticky');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
    $('#header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
});
```

and then add some css to this sticky class like this

```
#header.sticky {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #325052;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i used with "default_head_blocks.xml" to add custom js but its giving error as below : 

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(window).scroll(function () {

also i tried replacing "jQuery" with "$" but error still come

Comment: Your custom.js should be like this:`require([
    "jquery"
    ], function($){//your code goes here});`

Comment: @UtsavIIHGlobal did you manage to get the sticky header working ?

Comment: still same error.. sorry

Comment: Can you post the code and the error? If it is showing the same error, your code is not updated in pub/static file. You can deploy the content and check again.

Comment: @Utsav IIHGlobal did u get it working?

Comment: Thanks @Sejal Shah Its working fine. just one thing i needed to do is. this code will work only for desktop view. not for mobile or ipad view. how can i check for it ?