# Made category menu fixed or sticky

Tags: magento2, category, javascript, css

I tried to made the `category menu` **fixed or sticky** in the top. I read [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174144/magento-2-how-to-make-sticky-header-for-frontend/174147) question and it's seems work, but i don't know on which file i should to add the `javascript` and `CSS`. So, which file should i add the `JS` and `CSS` file? And how can i call the JS to `sticking all the category menu`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code to app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js and be sure that .CategoryNav have position relative, it's important.

```
$('.CategoryNav').mage('sticky', {
    container: '#maincontent',
    spacingTop: 100
});
```

(copy file from Luma theme with required modules 'jquery' and 'mage/mage').