# Make sticky header for Magento 2 problem

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, magento2.2.3

I'm following the answer in [this topic](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174144/magento-2-how-to-make-sticky-header-for-frontend/174147) to keep header sticky. So far I've created *vendor/theme/web/js/sticky.js* with the following content:

```
require([ "jquery" ], function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top && !($('#header').hasClass('sticky'))) {
            $('#header-2').addClass('sticky');
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('#header').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    });
});
```

and called this file inside *vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml*

```
<link src="js/sticky.js"/>
```

**Second part of this answer says:**

"add some css to this sticky class like this:"

```
#header.sticky {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #325052;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

How can I implement this part? I've tried creating a *css/sticky.css* file with the code above and link it on *default_head_blocks.xml* ( `<css src="css/sticky.css"/>` ), but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I forgot to replace some #header placeholders, correct code below.

**Update:** I've added padding ( to prevent pixel skipping ) and mobile support ( to pad correct element on mobile interface )

*vendor/theme/web/js/sticky.js* :

```
require([ "jquery" ], function($) {
    if( $(window).width() >= 768 ) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.page-header').offset().top && !($('.page-header').hasClass('sticky')) && !($('.sections.nav-sections').hasClass('padding'))) {
                $('.page-header').addClass('sticky');
                $('.sections.nav-sections').addClass('padding');
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
                $('.page-header').removeClass('sticky');
                $('.sections.nav-sections').removeClass('padding');
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.page-header').offset().top && !($('.page-header').hasClass('sticky')) && !($('.page-main').hasClass('paddingm'))) {
                $('.page-header').addClass('sticky');
                $('.page-main').addClass('paddingm');
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
                $('.page-header').removeClass('sticky');
                $('.page-main').removeClass('paddingm');
            }
        });
    }   
});
```

*vendor/theme/web/css/sticky.css* :

```
.sticky {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #131313;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 109px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.padding {
    padding-top: 126px;
}

.paddingm {
    padding-top: 107px;
}
```

( *max-height* and *padding-top* values depend on header's height )

Answer (score 5):

You can use default M2 Sticky

```js
define([
    'jquery', 
    'mage/mage', 
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {
    $('#header').mage('sticky', {
        container: '#maincontent',
        spacingTop: 0
    });
});
```

And CSS

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Missing steps?

Comment: which Magento version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

For Sticky Product page Image
Some time issue with sticky properties so
We can used jquery in direct phtml file for magento 2.

```
<script>

require([ "jquery" ], function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
            let mediaTop = $('.product.media').offset().top;
            let mediaHeight = $('.product.media').height() - 52;
            let mediaBottom = mediaTop + mediaHeight;
            $(window).scroll(() => {
                var width = $(window).width();
                if(width > 1024) {
                        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 200){
                            let infoBottom = $('.product-info-main').offset().top + $('.product-info-main').height();
                            if(mediaBottom <= infoBottom) {
                                let scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                                let mediaTopAdjust = Math.max((scrollTop - mediaTop), 0);
                                let newMediaBottom = mediaTop + mediaTopAdjust + mediaHeight;
                                let bottomHeightDiff = infoBottom - mediaBottom;
                                if(newMediaBottom <= infoBottom) {
                                    $('.product.media').css('top','0');
                                    $('.product.media').css('position', 'fixed');
                                } else {
                                        $('.product.media').css('top', bottomHeightDiff + 'px');
                                        $('.product.media').css('position', 'relative');
                                    }
                            }
                        } else {
                                $('.product.media').css('position', 'relative');
                                $('.product.media').css('margin-top', "");
                            }
                }
            });
    });
});

</script>
```